# Restricting user to edit the list item when it is opened by other user in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a list whcih is having custom list forms for new, view and edit. forms are developed using farm solution (SharePoint 2010). When two users are editing the same item and saving it at the same time then it is saving only one user data. It is not showing any error for second user but closing the form. Second user may think the form is saved but it is not saved. So I want to show message to second user like in outofbox list forms.

Please help me in this issue.

Regards
Anoosha

Answer (score 0):

well, it depends what event u are using. item adding or added. If u are using first one, you need validate the information from current item. C# is structural. Even if User A and User B put button "save" then one event start 1st and second 2nd.

at editing get current item from list and download all fields again and using "if" find out that the item u are editing is not changed, use beforepropties and afterpropeties. algoritm in pseudocode:

```
1. SPListItem item = CurrentItemDownload;
2. If(item != properties.beforepropeties)
3. Cancel.Submit
4. Show.Message //validation
```